# Redux form clearing field values

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I am using the redux  to hide and show components based on a value.
When I am switching between options I would like to clear the values.

How do I clear values from the state when switching between fields that are hiding and showing?

What is the recommended way validating each field?

Is it possible to completely remove the field from the state?

```
<div>
    <form>
      <Fields
       component={RadioButtonGroupField}
       names={['radioButtonGroup', 'nameTextField', 'nickNameTextField']}
      />
    </ form>
</div>

function RadioButtonGroupField(fields) {
    return(
      <div>
        <RadioButtonGroupComponent
          {...fields.radioButtonGroup.input}
          {...fields.radioButtonGroup.meta}
        />
        {
          (fields.radioButtonGroup.input.value === 'name' ||
          fields.radioButtonGroup.input.value === 'both') &&
          <NameTextFieldComponent
            {...fields.radioButtonGroup.input}
            {...fields.radioButtonGroup.meta}
          />
        }
        {
          (fields.radioButtonGroup.input.value === 'nickname' ||
          fields.radioButtonGroup.input.value === 'both') &&
           <NicknameTextFieldComponent
            {...fields.radioButtonGroup.input}
            {...fields.radioButtonGroup.meta}
          />
        }
      </div>
     );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does it matter if the other value is in the state? Seems like you could, upon submission, look at your radio value to determine which of the other values to use.

However, to answer your question, you could potentially put an `onChange` listener on your radio field, and (not forgetting to call the `fields.radioButtonGroup.input.onChange()`) dispatch a `change(value==='name' ? 'nickname' : 'name', null)` action to destroy the value in the input you want to ignore.

Comment: One last thing, what is the best way to add validation to each field?

Comment: You could either add a [field-level validation function](http://redux-form.com/6.6.1/examples/fieldLevelValidation/) or provide a validation function [for the entire record](https://redux-form.com/6.6.1/examples/syncValidation/).

Comment: I am not clear how I would add a `field-level validation function` to `Fields`? @erik-r can you please take a look at the comments from
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218272/redux-form-fields-component-and-validation . Can you please post your thoughts on adding validations to `Fields`?

Comment: Oops, you are correct. There is no field-level validation for `Fields`. For that you will need to validate the entire record.

Comment: Do you think that it should be a feature since there is a few ways one might want to validate `Features` as mentioned  by @dpwrussell here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218272/redux-form-fields-component-and-validation. I understand that you might be busy so if you need help I am more than happy to help.