# Redux Form Fields Component and Validation

Tags: redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I am using the redux  to hide and show components based on a value.

The Redux form documentation mentions the following:

> Connecting to multiple fields should be used sparingly, as it will require the entire  component to re-render every time any of the fields it is connected to change. This can be a performance bottleneck. Unless you absolutely need to, you should connect to your fields individually with .

I am unclear if my solution to hiding and showing fields based on radio buttons is good enough to use `Fields` giving the warning to use sparingly.

Can you please clarify if my component merits enough reason to use `Fields`. If not, what is an alternative way to implement?

Also, how does `fields` implement validations?

```
<div>
    <form>
      <Fields
       component={RadioButtonGroupField}
       names={['radioButtonGroup', 'nameTextField', 'nickNameTextField']}
      />
    </ form>
</div>

function RadioButtonGroupField(fields) {
    return(
      <div>
        <RadioButtonGroupComponent
          {...fields.radioButtonGroup.input}
          {...fields.radioButtonGroup.meta}
        />
        {
          (fields.radioButtonGroup.input.value === 'name' ||
          fields.radioButtonGroup.input.value === 'both') &&
          <NameTextFieldComponent
            {...fields.radioButtonGroup.input}
            {...fields.radioButtonGroup.meta}
          />
        }
        {
          (fields.radioButtonGroup.input.value === 'nickname' ||
          fields.radioButtonGroup.input.value === 'both') &&
           <NicknameTextFieldComponent
            {...fields.radioButtonGroup.input}
            {...fields.radioButtonGroup.meta}
          />
        }
      </div>
     );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another way you could do that, selecting the specific value using redux-form selectors (http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/docs/api/Selectors.md/) from the redux store in your `mapStateToProps` and then conditionally rendering certain components.

However, I think that `Fields` is exactly what you should use in this circumstance. I think that warning is largely to warn people not to go and put their entire form into Fields, having those 3 fields rerender is no big deal.

The thought process that led to the creation of `Fields` in the first place is probably the best way to get a handle on this: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/841

Comment: How would I go about implementing validations with using Fields?

Comment: That is a good question @eNddy! I'm not sure exactly what it would mean to validate `Fields`. There is no validate argument as I'm sure you have noticed. The obvious way would be to jsut use syncValidation: http://redux-form.com/6.6.1/examples/syncValidation/

Comment: I was think if could be possible to have something like:  
  `<Fields component={RadioButtonGroupField} names={['radioButtonGroup', 'nameTextField', 'nickNameTextField']} validations={[radioButtonGroupValidation, nameTextFieldValidation, nickNameTextField]} /> ` . 
@dpwrussell do you think something like that would be possible? I seems nice not to have to pollute the global async validations?

Comment: I am not trying to validate `Fields` as a whole instead i am trying to add validation to each individual component without using the global sync.

Comment: Agreed, my answer was just the current state. There are 3 things you might want to do right? 1) Validate the 3 fields independently (i.e. 3 validators), 2) Validate the 3 fields together. The fact that they are an interacting group would make it very likely that you'd need to validate them together. 3) Both (1) and (2). So in your example that might be 1, 3 or 4 validators depending on what you want to do. My advice would be to set out this use case in an issue on GitHub as I think it a reasonable improvement to forms. Fields is pretty new, so it's not surprising there are missing features.